# Responsive horizontal menu

Tags: html, navigation, responsive-design

I am trying to create menu with fix max-width where width of items in menu will be responsive. I created the samples, where show what i coded.

http://codepen.io/tanotify/pen/asjde

The problem is when i change size of browser everything goes wrong and i do not know how to fix it. The words in navigation can change in future and it is the problem too. The solution which i try to find must be responsive for the words too.

Comment: What do you mean with "must be responsive for the words too"? It's quite natural for words to bump onto the next line if they run out of space.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like the third example in http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/DCshm ?

I've removed the set width for each link

```
#navigation li{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
/* width: 16%; */
}
```

and used a pixel based padding between links

```
#navigation-padding li{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
/*padding: 0 4.5%; */
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Responsive navbars can be a real challenge ... trying to fit everything into the limited space.

If you need more control over the results, you might want to consider using @media queries, where you specify different CSS styles at different viewports or window sizes.

Start by adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
 to the head of your document.

Then at the end of your existing CSS you could add

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

#navigation li{
display: box;
}

}
```

This would make the nav bar collapse to a vertical list at viewports 767px and below. You can change this pixel width and the css selectors inside to whatever you want.

[Here's a link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html) to get you started with what you do using @media queries.

Good luck!